# Should I edit questions to improve the case of the title?

Tags: discussion, edits

The [StackOverflow help page on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) says that one of the reasons to edit a question is "To fix grammar and spelling mistakes".

To this end I would edit titles with incorrect casing e.g.

- "how do i add some numbers in java?" to "How do I add some numbers in Java?"
- "Reverse a Really Long Word in Python" to "Reverse a really long word in Python"

However upon doing so, my edit was rejected by three out of five reviewers as "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

Should I not bother performing such edits?

Comment: Was that the ONLY thing that could be fixed on the post?

Comment: Yes. The body of the question was short with correct spelling and grammar and was easy to understand.

Comment: I think you mean [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6233823). That didn't need editing, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do ask that suggested edits be *substantial,* because it does require the time and effort of several reviewers to evaluate them.

Your first example doesn't seem like it would meet the six-character minimum requirement for a suggested edit.  Your second example is an invalid edit; Title Case is Perfectly Acceptable in a Title.

Comment: wHAT ABOUT THIS CASE? tHAT i FORGOT THE NAME TO? oR tITLE cASE cAPLOCKS?

Comment: Hmm-- I disagree on title case. Case is *important* in some languages. I Also Find It Highly Annoying To Read As Each Separate Word Seems Emphasized.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: Self-evident.

Comment: Yes, I Agree. It Is Very Annoying.